# My Documents type folder

Tags: windows-xp

I want to create a folder that mounts to some other place just like default My Documents. It has a different target tab in properties. I can't create a folder with that tab. I need it because shortcuts doesn't act like folders in other programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but what I think you are asking for is a [Junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

> In computing, an NTFS junction point is a feature of the NTFS file system that provides the ability to create a link to a directory that is, for most intents and purposes, the same as the directory itself. This has many benefits over a Windows shell shortcut (.lnk) file, such as allowing access to files within the directory via Windows Explorer, the Command Prompt, etc.

On XP you can use the Microsoft Sysinternals [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) app to create these.

I suggest you read the above linked Wiki article carefully, particularly the [Warning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Warning) and [Observed effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Observed_effects) sections

Comment: No bashing but I didn't know it could be this complicated. It was so easy in Linux.

Comment: Vista and 7 have added Symbolic Links (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) which are much more Linux-y

Comment: You can't create a symbolic link without administratiev privileges, though. You can create junctions, however, just fine.